# How to set up an OAuth2 Authentication Provider with AWS API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, oauth-2.0

AWS has an [API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/), that makes it pretty easy to set up, manage and monitor your API.
However, the security authorization settings that you can set for resource methods is limited to AWS-IAM (which to my understanding is an internal vpn role?).

It seems that my research on this subject has been pointing me to setting up an [AWS Cognito pool](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/identity/identity-pools/), but when I go to configure one in my aws console, the options for providers are: `Amazon`, `Facebook`, `Google+`, `Twitter`, `OpenID`, and `Custom`. I guess, in that case, I would use `Custom`? Then setup my own EC2 instance as an OAuth2 Authentication Provider Server.

Given that Oauth2 is so popular these days it surprises me that there isn't an AWS service for this; it seems they've gone the whole OpenId or SAML route instead. It also surprises me that there is a lack of guides on how to quickly setup an Oauth2 Provider in the cloud.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I decided not to use OAuth

Comment: so how did you decide to do your authentication for the AWS API?

Comment: Using a reverse proxy

Answer (score 43):

(1) Do you want to implement OAuth 2.0 endpoints ([authorization endpoint](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.1) and [token endpoint](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.2)) on API Gateway? In other words, do you really want to implement an OAuth 2.0 server ([RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749)) on API Gateway?

(2) Or, do you want to protect your Web APIs implemented on API Gateway by OAuth 2.0 [access token](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.4)?

These two are completely different things.

Because it seems you wanted to select OAuth 2.0 instead of AWS-IAM, I guess what you wanted to do is (2). If so, you can find an example here: **[Amazon API Gateway + AWS Lambda + OAuth](https://www.authlete.com/documents/apigateway_lambda_oauth)**

---

Updated on 2016-Apr-6

On Feb 11, 2016, a blog entry of [AWS Compute Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/jp/blogs/compute/), "[Introducing custom authorizers in Amazon API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/jp/blogs/compute/introducing-custom-authorizers-in-amazon-api-gateway)", announced that **Custom Authorizer** had been introduced into Amazon API Gateway. Thanks to this mechanism, an API built on Amazon API Gateway can delegate validation of a Bearer token (such as an OAuth or SAML token) presented by a client application to an external authorizer.

How to protect APIs built on Amazon API Gateway by OAuth access tokens utilizing the new mechanism, Custom Authorier, is described in "[Amazon APi Gateway Custom Authorizer + OAuth](https://www.authlete.com/documents/article/custom_authorizer)".

---

FYI:

OAuth 2.0 is a mechanism for authorization, not authentication. But people often use OAuth 2.0 for authentication and there are many software libraries and services using OAuth 2.0 for authentication.

Cognito (Identity) is a solution related to authentication, not authorization.

Custom in Cognito is a place to specify OpenID Connect Providers. OpenID Connect is a solution for authentication. What makes things complicated is "OpenID Connect is built on top of OAuth 2.0". See [OpenID Connect site](http://openid.net/connect/) for details.

Comment: I want to use an AWS service to easily register external users to authenticate and assign authorizations using the OAuth2 headers and workflow when integrating with my API through my API Gateway. So I guess #2.

Comment: OAuth 2 is not only for authorization. "Resource Owner Password" flow is for authentication. As noted, OpenID Connect is for authentication and is invented to cover some flaws of OAuth 2.

Comment: To get a better understanding, would it be correct to say that by using custom authorizer, we do not need to depend on obtaining the delegate token using the oauth /delegate post request which is then signed and used for making an AWS api request? In other words, I can directly make an aws rest api request using the id_token as the bearer header instead of getting the delegation token first?

Comment: In the flow when using a custom authorizer, who generates and validates the OAuth token? Do we need to write code in the Lambda function to integrate with a third party IDP?

Comment: Doesn't authorization pre-suppose authentication? If an identity is authorized for some particular access, doesn't that pre-suppose that the identity has to be identified first, that the identity is therefore authenticated? I understand a JWT can pack authorization information, and this may not necessarily include user information, so the individual user may not be uniquely identified, but the fact that a valid JWT is provided still implies that the user has been given access to construct the JWT and is therefore authenticated somewhere down the line?

Answer (score 13):

AWS API Gateway supports Amazon Cognito OAuth2 Scopes [now](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-enable-cognito-user-pool.html). You can create Amazon Cognito user pool authoriser and configure it as your [Authorisation method in API Gateway.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmC05.png) In order to make use of OAuth scopes, you need to configure a [resource server and custom scopes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-define-resource-servers.html) with your Cognito userpool.
You can configure multiple [app clients](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-app-settings.html) in Cognito userpool with different scopes or request different scopes from your application code while authenticating users from your Userpool. Based on the scope received in the [access token](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-with-identity-providers.html#amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-the-access-token) from Cognito, API Gateway will allow/deny the caller of your APIs. A step-by-step guide to implement this feature can be found [here](https://medium.com/@awskarthik82/part-1-securing-aws-api-gateway-using-aws-cognito-oauth2-scopes-410e7fb4a4c0)

Comment: Does this mean that I can just use the user pool for API keys and secrets, that is, store the secret as the password and the API key as the username? or would that be bad..