# How to make AWS API Gateway authenticate users similar to AWS ALB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I know it's possible to have AWS ALB authenticate users:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/listener-authenticate-users.html

For API Gateway, I would like the same, i.e. that user's are redirected to OAuth2.0 provider, if they don't provide a JWT token in a request to a protected route.

I have looked into Lambda authorizers, but they are only for validating a provided JWT token, not for carrying out a full OAuth2.0 authentication flow with redirects etc.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32236568/how-to-set-up-an-oauth2-authentication-provider-with-aws-api-gateway